# RadlistBox fails in google chrome

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have radlistbox in pop-up which is causing a run-time Error "System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format error is thrown." .when the same  pop-up is been opened in IE or FireFox it works properly without any error or interruptions.Please Provide solution to this problem.

Comment: That means your string is not a correct format. How about showing your work first and tell which line you get this error? Without that, it is not possible to help you.

Comment: @SonerGönül This is browser based Issue. Same functionality works on other browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to Anti-virus the pop-up was acting weird.After Disabling the anti-virus it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

HTML and JavaScript and the way they work differ from browser to browser, so you need to post the code that causes the problem so someone can help you. For example, Chrome provides float numbers for dimensions and positions when zoomed, so this may be the cause. This broke some controls that store such numbers in the client state. This page offers workarounds and the easier way to get a fix is to upgrade your Telerik controls version http://feedback.telerik.com/Project/108/Feedback/Details/144661-fix-system-formatexception-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-thrown-o